# What is the best way to serialize the response to JSON inside middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a canonical way to leverage the configured `JsonOutputFormatter` inside ASP.NET middleware? Or, more generically, is there a better way to serialize the response to JSON than explicitly calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` in my middleware?

Currently, I have the following code:

```
public static void HandleHealthRequests(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Map(new PathString("/health"), builder =>
    {
        builder.Run(async context =>
        {
            string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { DateTime.UtcNow, Version = _version });
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.ContentLength = response.Length;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
        });
    });
}
```

This works fine, but calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` directly and manipulating the `Response` directly doesn't feel right.

I looked at resolving the `JsonOutputFormatter` to leverage it directly but it requires an `OutputFormatterContext` which looks too complicated to set up. Additionally, I also tried just leveraging `JsonOutputFormatter.SerializerSettings` but found it to be `null` on app startup so my code was throwing when the process started.

Comment: Note this has nothing to do with Map.

Comment: This looks fine for a simple component. JsonOutputFormatter is for a more complex environment like MVC.

Comment: yeah, i hopped on jabbr and @davidfowl basically said as much. thanks

Comment: @DavidPeden Did you find a more elegant solution for this?

Comment: nope. it's simple and works. obviously you could bundle the calls into a method or something if you wanted to tidy it up or reuse it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similiar problem, i just want to use the same configuration for all my json responses regardless they are inside a middleware or a filter or controller... with the new versions of .net core (at least with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 1.1.2`) i use the  `WriteObject(TextWriter writer, object value)` method inside the formatter, i resolve the `JsonOutputFormatter` with dependency injection inside my middleware or filter and use that WriteObject method for serialization.

```
var stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
jsonOutputFormatter.WriteObject(stringWriter, value);
var responseBody = stringWriter.ToString();
```